# Is it rude to be messaging your supervisor if he is in hospital?

Tags: phd, etiquette, academic-life

My advisor is currently in hospital waiting to have an operation. It is nothing serious but nevertheless he is away from work. I've noticed that some of my lab mates continue messaging him despite him being in this situation. I wonder if this is a cultural thing and whether this is actually normal? I am in Canada but my background is European if that makes sense.

Comment: This depends on the advisor and what he may have communicated. If in doubt, don't, other than for really essential things.

Comment: You just made another post saying your prof wants you gone... what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Next post: I have made my supervisor disappeared or I have landed my supervisor in the hospital permanently.  What's next?

Comment: What do you mean "messaging"? Texts, Slack? Absolutely not. Emails, sure

Comment: I swear I have not done anything to him 

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Absolutes are not so absolutes: I don't mind being texted by a PhD student if I'm sick, even in hospital. And I also know others who don't mind. So, better to just ask.

Comment: related? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/179190/i-think-my-advisor-wants-me-gone-what-do-i-do

Comment: @quantum being charitable, Jojo22 may have been working on hypotheticals. Evaluate a Q&A by the quality of the answers it gathered. Attempting to discern OP's motives or real life issues from their Q&A is a fool's errand at best. The Author is dead, long live the Content.

Comment: @Mindwin: What did you do to Jojo22?!  :-O

Comment: I swear I have not done anything to him  – 
Jojo22
18 hours ago

Comment: *It is nothing serious* is what hey told you. Details may be none of your buisness

Comment: Being in hospital is imho serious. The "nothing serious" means likely that yes, it is serious, only his life is not in danger. Being in sickness leave, but not in hospital, that might be not serious.

Answer (score 41):

It's appropriate to contact your supervisor to wish them a speedy recovery.

It's not appropriate to ask your supervisor to help you immediately while they are hospitalized or ill.

It may or may not be appropriate to let your supervisor know you need help with something when they are feeling better.

Personally, I prefer for students to let me know about their progress while I am sick.  At least it's more pleasant than thinking about my own progress.

Comment: "Personally, I prefer for students to let me know about their progress while I am sick. " <- but that's something you would need to tell them explicitly. I would assume people in hospitals are not to be bothered about work.

Comment: Yeah, agree with @einpoklum - to me personally, it would seem like it offers some distraction when you're lying in bed all day. But unless stated directly, I would assume that they are unavailable.

Comment: @Jeroen But is it expected that they actually read emails while sick? I would assume they don't (if they don't want to). And with that assumption, it seems fair to send emails (with the expectation that they will read them eventually, when they are well again). But the assumption that they don't read emails if they don't want to might be a cultural issue.

Answer (score 32):

#### Messaging, yes.  Expecting replies, no.

If people tend to "take their work home with them", they may well want to keep in touch with what's going on.  Your supervisor may be one of those people, which is why his students/colleagues are in the habit of messaging him.

However you do need to recognise that responses when they're out of office will depend on what they're currently doing.  If they're sat watching TV, perhaps they're fine responding to messages.  If they're on a date, not so much.  If they're asleep, of course not.  If they're unwell or going through some medical issue, it will completely depend on how they're feeling.

So if you want to send an update on your status, that's probably fine.  If you're asking a question and expecting a reply within any kind of timescale, that's a big no-no.

Comment: I think this could be expanded to mention that this also limits what type of communication you can use. E-mail or inter-department paper mail is certainly fine, since that's obviously asynchronous. If your team uses Slack or something, it is fine if you're using it asynchronously but not fine if your team primarily uses it synchronously and you don't specify that this is an asynchronous request ("Hey, when you get back..."). If they have a work phone and already treat text asynchronously, that's fine, but if they treat it synchronously then probably not fine.

Comment: @user3067860 That would still make assumptions.  Even with paper mail, there's an expectation of a timely reply - but if you're in ICU with tubes in your arms, that reply isn't going to happen. :)  I think the more general case is better.  Whatever your means of communication, if they're out of office then assume you might not get a reply until they're back.